# Why is QScrollArea not taking vertical scroll bar width into account?

Tags: qt, pyqt

Consider the following example,

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class scrolldemo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(scrolldemo, self).__init__(parent)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 600))

        scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidget(widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(scroll)
        self.setWindowTitle("Scroll demo")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = scrolldemo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The widget has a size that is slightly too large vertically, which adds a vertical scroll bar. However, the vertical scroll bar takes up space that was taken up by the widget itself. This requires a horizontal scroll bar too, making the window look like this:

[image: Scroll area with vertical and horizontal scroll bars]

I'm okay with the vertical scroll bar, but horizontal scroll bars are ungainly. Observe that the extra space needed for the horizontal scroll bar is exactly the width of the vertical bar.

This can be worked around by overriding the `sizeHint` method to include the vertical scroll bar's width,

```py
class ScrollAreaWithVerticalBar(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        bar_width = self.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width()
        return QtCore.QSize(hint.width() + bar_width, hint.height())
```

[image: QScrollArea with extra widght]

This produces a slightly wider QScrollArea that no longer needs the ungainly horizontal scroll bar. I got this idea by looking at [a closed Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10265) related to this problem. However, that bug report was closed as "out of scope", which makes me think that this isn't a bug at all and I'm using QScrollArea incorrectly, and my incorrect use also is requiring a workaround.

So what should I be doing instead?

Comment: Use [setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop) to permanently hide the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @ekhumoro No, this isn't right. If the user resizes the window, they could need the horizontal scroll bar. I just want the window to be the right size so that initially horizontal scrolling isn't necessary.